# Check Update and Refresh Page

Tags: c#

I Have a Messaging web application whose conversation page needs to check for a new message at a fixed interval (say 10 sec) and refresh itself if any new message available. I don't want to put a static HTML refresh as it causes page to reload even if no new message is there !

Any help is widely appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajaxSetup(
        {
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#content').hide();
                $('#loading').show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#content').show();
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#content').show();
            }
        });
        var $container = $("#content");
        $container.load("page.php");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.load('page.php');
        }, 9000);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: although not exactly what i needed...but is much better than reloading the page every 10 sec ;)...i used it as a workaround...thanks !